# ¿Cómo puedo lanzar mi aplicación de Android desde una página web?

Tags: android, aplicación-web

Me han pedido que haga que mi aplicación de Android Studio pueda lanzarse desde una página web o un servidor web, de tal modo que se pueda ejecutar en cualquier dispositivo móvil sin necesidad de instalar la apk. ¿Es eso posible? Todos los tutoriales que he mirado hablan sobre cómo convertir páginas web a aplicaciones de Android o sobre cómo subir la apk de la aplicación para luego instalarla en un dispositivo móvil, pero nada sobre cómo hacer que mi propia aplicación se lance en un dispositivo con tan sólo poner el enlace a un servidor web o a una página web.

¿Se puede hacer algo así?

Comment: Es probable que sea posible, [si es esto lo que quieres](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3469908/5587982). Puedes revisar también [Android doc](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html) al respecto.

Comment: no, no busco poner un link en mi aplicación de android, lo que busco es una forma de poner mi aplicación en la web de tal forma que en cuanto alguien entre en mi página o servidor (`www.miaplicacion.com`, por ejemplo) directamente se lance la app, como si de una página web se tratara. No se si me explico.

Comment: No, no entiendo. ¿Que se lance dónde la aplicación, en el dispositivo de la persona que haga clic en el enlace? No podrá lanzarse si la persona no la instala en su dispositivo, me parece. Y deberá tener activada la opción de *Instalar apps de fuentes desconocidas*. Pero lanzarse así sin más, imposible. Deberá instalarse y luego lanzarse.

Comment: Eso es lo que me temía. Lo que me están pidiendo es que mi aplicación sea como una página web escrita en html, que cuando alguien haga click en el enlace la aplicación se lance sin trabas y sin necesidad de instalación. ¿Eso es algo imposible, verdad?

Comment: Me parece que eso es imposible. No sé si del lado de [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?authuser=0) se pueda hacer algo parecido a lo que quieres. El lanzamiento de una app debe contar con el consentimiento del usuario de alguna manera.

Comment: Lo que suponía, muchas gracias por responder tan pronto.

Comment: Si he entendido bien lo que quieres es algo como lo que sucede al abrir el enlace de youtube, de Google play o hasta de la app de stackExchange, que si la app esta instalada en el dispositivo, el enlace se abre con la app no con el navegador.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creo que lo que buscas son las Instants Apps. Son bastante recientes y ejecutan aplicaciones android a partir de urls sin necesidad de instalarlas.

Mas info: https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/

Comment: Voy a ponerme a investigarlo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

revisen aqui
https://www.altavoz.net/altavoz/blog/desarrollo/que-son-las-instant-apps-y-como-funcionan que viene por ahi, la idea, a mi tambien me han pedido lo mismo asi que o lo implementamos nosotros o buscamos la respuesta que ya ha de existir
En mi caso, seria como desde mi sitio web levanto una app que existe (bastante parecido) pero de esa aplicacion no tengo mucha informacion (ni funcionamiento ni objetivo, ni nada)

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/321260)